# I want to close my default camera activity(started using MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) on some event from my activity. How can I achieve this?

Tags: android

I want to close my default camera activity(started using `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`) on some event from my activity. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple method :  finish() which closes the current activity. If you wish to go back to the previous activity you can call a method that does that if you have it setup correctly. Android developer sections should be able to help with the 'back' thing

Comment: I don't have context of my default camera activity. i started camera activity with startActivityForResult(Intent).